# Python3 - как преобразовать строку в ansi?

Tags: python, unicode

Подскажите, у меня есть код вида

```
str0 ="\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1"
```

это бинарные данные, которые куда-то копируются. Этот код прекрасно работает в Python2, но при переходе на третью версию после каждого символа появляется еще \00, вероятно из-за каких-то внутренних особенностей юникода в питоне. Вопрос - мне преобразовать строку в ansi , в общем чтобы было как в python2 ?

Comment: оно в ASCII не может быть преобразовано, так как есть за пределами 128 значения.

Comment: ок, как сделать с этой строки строку как во втором питоне?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не бинарные данные. Бинарные данные (*bytes*) в Питоне задаются с литеры *b* `b'...'`.

Попробуйте преобразовать вашу строку в *bytes* и работать уже с ними.

```
bytes0 = str0.encode('latin-1')
print(bytes0)
```

```
b'1\xc9\xf7\xe1'
```

Comment: Как-то странно оно преобразовывает. "\xE8\x89\x45\xE4\x68\x78\x65\x63\x00\x68\x57" выходит не пойми что b'\xe8\x89E\xe4hxec\x00hW'

Comment: Почему не пойми что? Например (с конца) буква W имеет код \x57. Буква h - \x68. Просто при печати оно выводится в виде кодов только для непечатных символов. Если вывести побайтно в шестнадцатиричном виде, то увидите, что всё на месте: `b'\xe8\x89E\xe4hxec\x00hW'.hex()   >>>   
'e88945e468786563006857'`